# Camera and photo library together in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am creating an app in which I need to show both camera and photo library together in same screen. top half of the screen will have the camera and bottom half of the screen will have photo library. See the screenshot.

[image: See the screenshot]

Also please let me know if it is feasible or not and if it is possible then please help me how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: (If you wanted to implement custom camera and photos library).You can create custom camera in half screen using AVCaptureSession. And for Photos library in half view you can fetch Photos form Photos library and create Collection view from it.

Comment: To add a camera view, look at AVFoundation. To add a list of photos, look at    Photos framework.

Comment: is that feasible in terms of memory pressure and performance issues?

Comment: chek this out [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717115/how-to-uiimagepickercontroller-for-camera-and-photo-library-in-the-same-time-in)

Comment: Custom photo library is just a CollectionView so i dont think it will increase any Memory pressure with custom camera along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tried the [instagram](http://www.instagram.com/developer/) SDK? Has a method that works for me

Comment: is that same what I am looking for?