# Prompt iOS user to select JPEG to be processed by app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've done this in Android with but can't seem to find any information on doing this in iOS. Basically:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/JPEG");
Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "File");
startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

Then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.

            // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
        }
    }
}
```

What/where is the corresponding terminology & sample code?

(Objective-C Examples Appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit primarily goes to other answers for reference but here's the Objective-C example code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Callback with image data:

```
/*============================================================================*/

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

/*============================================================================*/
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker release];

    UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (!image)
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData* imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
}
```

Delegate/`self` must be:

```
UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The UIImagePickerController view controller in iOS is a standard way of allowing the user to choose pictures from there media library. The Apple documentation on this is available at [UIImagePickerController.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) There is also a good tutorial that shows how to use UIImagePickerController at [Picking images with UIImagePickerController in Swift 5](https://theswiftdev.com/2019/01/30/picking-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-5/).

Answer (score 0):

This should exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717882/2968456

Basically you need to use Apple's built-in UIImagePicker framework.